# Javascript rock paper scissors project

Tags: javascript, function

```js
var rock = rock;
var paper= paper;
var snip = snip;

var playerOneName= prompt("what is your name");
playerOne = choice();
var playerTwoName = prompt("what is your name");
playerTwo=choice();


function choice(pick){
 prompt("rock paper or snip");
}
if(playerOne === rock && playerTwo === snip){
    alert(playerOneName + " " + "Wins");
}else if(playerOne === paper && playerTwo === rock){
    alert(playerOneName + " " + "Wins");
}else if(playerOne === snip && playerTwo === paper){
    alert(playerOneName + " " + "Wins");
}else if(playerTwo === rock && playerOne === snip){
   alert(playerTwoName + " " + "Wins");
}else if(playerTwo === paper && playerOne === rock){
    alert(playerTwoName + " " + "Wins");
}else if(playerTwo === snip && playerOne === paper){
   alert(playerTwoName + " " + "Wins");
}else if(playerOne === playerTwo){
 alert("it's a tie try again");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="rps.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
 <li>Rock</li>
 <li>Paper</li>
 <li>Snip</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello All,
I'm back with a very new question. For some reason when I run my code for this game of rock paper scissors... it's constantly telling me that player one wins. The issue that I discovered is that it's always choosing the if statement and not the else if. If someone could help that would be great!
Thanks again for your time.Also this is my first week learning javascript... It's kinda of sad that this many people would down vote my question... This is the reason why most people are afraid to ask question fyi...

Comment: You don't return the value from `choice `

Comment: Your function `choice()` doesn't return anything. You need `return prompt("rock paper or snip");`

Comment: I know this may sound dumb but what do I return it too? This is my third day learning javascript so I don't know much lol

Comment: So under the prompt type
return prompt("rock paper or snip")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this corrected and verified JavaScript Code -

```
var rock = rock;
var paper= paper;
var snip = snip;

var playerOneName= prompt("what is your name");
playerOne = choice();
var playerTwoName = prompt("what is your name");
playerTwo=choice();

alert('Player 1 Chose  - '+ playerOne + 'Player 2 Chose  - '+playerTwo);

function choice(pick){
    return(prompt("rock paper or snip"));  //return the prompt value
}

if(playerOne === 'rock' && playerTwo === 'snip'){
    alert(playerOneName + ' ' + 'Wins');
}else if(playerOne === 'paper' && playerTwo === 'rock'){
    alert(playerOneName + ' ' + 'Wins');
}else if(playerOne === 'snip' && playerTwo === 'paper'){
    alert(playerOneName + ' ' + 'Wins');
}else if(playerTwo === 'rock' && playerOne === 'snip'){
   alert(playerTwoName + ' ' + 'Wins');
}else if(playerTwo === 'paper' && playerOne === 'rock'){
    alert(playerTwoName + ' ' + 'Wins');
}else if(playerTwo === 'snip' && playerOne === 'paper'){
   alert(playerTwoName + ' ' + 'Wins');
}else if(playerOne === playerTwo){
    alert('its a tie try again');
}
```

**Corrections** -

1. Return value in `choice()` function. Prompt has the return value which is to be received and returned in the function.
2. Alert and check the values for debugging purpose. Always try this to know whats happening inside the code.

Comment: My Pleasure. Please mark this as an answer if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return` the entered value from window.prompt. i.e

`function choice(pick){
    var answer = prompt("rock paper or snip");
    return answer;
}`

This way you can get what the user had typed in the window prompt. There are some case where you may have to check for `null` values though. 
More reading here [at Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)